# Azure Media Services upload from HTML from

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-storage, azure-media-services

I have an MVC4 site allowing video to be uploaded. It's hosted on Azure as an Azure website.

As such I don't have access to any local storage in which to cache the Video before shipping it off to Azure Media Services to transcode/deliver.

The upload process is a HTML5 chunked upload going straight to an WebApi controller. This controller is called for each uploaded chunk of the file.

What is my best option for getting the whole uploaded video into AMS to convert?

I presumed appending data to a blob would be the right way to do it. However, I can't seem to find any information on how to append to an existing blob.
Also, I'm concerned this would cause concurrency issues if there were a random delay in the handler causing data corruption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And videos of what size will you be uploading? Free mode WebSites give you 1G, Shared and Reserved - 10G.

Check out [this project](https://github.com/astaykov/WaMediaWeb), as it is MVC4 Media Services explorer.

Also check out [this blog post](http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/) on how to upload directly to Blob Storage using HTML5. To upload to the Asset via HTML5, you must first get a [Shared Access Locator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974308.aspx) and upload files to the container you get SAS from the Media Service.

Comment: Across multiple users simultaneously uploading will likely be >1G. But It's on a shared instance. So 10G should be plenty.

I can't remember where I read you don't get any local storage. But if the above is correct. Then I'll just upload to the server, then pass it onto Blob Storage!